# MySQL Select Row Values as Key=>Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, optimization

I have a MySQL structure set up similar to this from Basecamp:

**bc_projects**

> project_id | title
>                      |
>   active
>  2618731   | 'Sample Title'    |
>   1
>  2618732   | 'Sample Title 2' | 0

**bc_todolists**

> todolist_id | project_id | title
>  6731098   | 2618731
>     | 'Launch Status'
>  6731099   | 2618731
>     | 'Some Other List'

**bc_todos**

> todo_id     | todolist_id | title
>                    |
>   completed     | content
>  39180738 | 6731098
>     | 'Client Signoff' | 1366041432 | 'YYYY-MM-DD'
>   39180739 | 6731098   | 'Team Signoff' | null                | ''

What I need to do is get all project related details into 1 row for each project (or some other equally effective SQL)

The next part is even tricker. I would like to get either content or completed from **bc_todos** depending on whether or not content is *null* or = *'YYYY-MM-DD'*. I have attempted to run this myself but am stuck at this point. Here is what i have so far:

```
SELECT 
    bc_projects.title
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(todolist_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM `bc_todolists` WHERE project_id = bc_projects.project_id) AS lists
FROM 
    bc_projects
WHERE 
    bc_projects.active = 1
```

I know I can pull the data from **bc_todos** using the joined lists in the query now, but the key value pairing is messing my head up. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: easy enough: fetch a row using your DB library's standard fetch functions, then `var_dump($row)`. you'll see EXACTLY what key/values to use.

Comment: That will give me multiple rows for 1 project correct? I want all of the data in 1 row if possible. In order to limit the additional queries I have to run as there are over 200 projects at this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want

SELECT 
    a.title,

```
GROUP_CONCAT(b.todolist_id SEPARATOR ',') AS lists,

CASE WHEN c.content IS NULL

     THEN GROUP_CONCAT(c.completed SEPARATOR ',')

ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(c.content SEPARATOR ',')

END as outlist
```

FROM     bc_projects a

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `bc_todolists` b ON a.project_id = b.project_id

LEFT OUTER JOIN bc_todos c ON b.todolist_id = c. todolist_id
```

WHERE     a.active = 1

Comment: That gives me something more to work with, thanks. Will see what I cam make with that.